# a href link(s) will not work in <p> tags

Tags: html, css, xhtml, hyperlink, paragraph

a href links ceased to work while in p tags? they work when I put them in H3 tags, but the layout/style sheet formatting seems to go out the window. This makes me wonder if it has something to do with the sites css or xhtml.

**Code snippet - link wont work:**

```
<div id="written_content">
<div id="header_image"></div>
         <h1>How we do it</h1>
         <div id="casestudies">                       
              <p><a href="pdf/3Rivers FCU Case Study.pdf" target="_blank">3Rivers Federal Credit Union</a>
<br />
<br />
Momentum developed a three-pronged, integrated approach with 3Rivers to maximize market potential and increase existing branch productivity.</p>
```

**This snippet allows the link to work but messes with formatting:**

```
 <div id="written_content">
<div id="header_image"></div>
         <h1>How we do it</h1>
         <div id="casestudies">                       
              <h2><p><a href="pdf/3Rivers FCU Case Study.pdf" target="_blank">3Rivers Federal Credit Union</a></p><h2>

<p>Momentum developed a three-pronged, integrated approach with 3Rivers to maximize market potential and increase existing branch productivity.</p>
```

**Here is my css:**

```
 #written_content {
width: 500px;
float: left;
height: auto;
margin-top: 85px;
margin-left: 47px;
 }

h1 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #333;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 8px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
 }
 h2 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: lighter;
float: left;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
color: #999;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-style: normal;
}


#written_content p {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
width: 465px;
margin-top: 60px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-align: justify;
color: #999;
line-height: 17px;
}

 #casestudies{

font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
width: 500px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-align: justify;
color: #999;
line-height: 17px;
```

This was the last problem I thought I would have. Does anyone know of why this problem is accuring?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ceased to work'? What do they do instead, or what don't they do that they should do?

Comment: The cursor doesn't change and when you click on the link it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The links are formatted as links... they are blue and there is a line under them

Comment: David - Thanks for the response, I don't know if you can help but I have the code right where I'd like it, format wise, but the link still doesnt act like a link.

Comment: This is what I have...............<div id="casestudies"> <h2><a class="link" href="pdf/3Rivers FCU Case Study.pdf" target="_blank">3Rivers Federal Credit Union</a></h2><p><br /> Momentum developed a three-pronged, integrated approach with 3Rivers to maximize market potential and increase existing branch productivity.</p>

Answer (score 2):

I set up a little fiddle for you, with just your code, and it seems to work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/TGVWv/

There where a few missing closing tags in your code snippets, but i suspect that is a copying mistake.

Definitly go for your first html sample, as the second was produces invalid html. `<p>` is not allowed inside `<h2`>, and would be semanticly incorrect as well. It would probably work in most browsers, but is a bad idea for SEO in completly unenecassary.

Again, i spot no mistake in your link, nothing that would explain why it does not work for you. Perhaps you can provide a link to the actual page it is on?...

**edit:**
the page you provided has in issue that is not related to the actual link. There is a div positioned on top of it, be it transparent. This causes you to not be able to acces the link. Try updating your css with something like this (you might have to play with the numbers a bit):

```
.sidebar {
height: 150px;
width: 400px;
text-align: right;
position: absolute;
top: 230px;
right: 0;
}
```

This causes your sidebar to shrink and no longer be on top of your link.

Comment: http://momentum.freeiz.com/casestudies.htm

Comment: @MagX, 25 Errors, 43 warning(s) according to http://validator.w3.org (so please get the syntax right first).

Comment: @PeterVR thanks Peter Man! Dumb mistake, thanks for helping out the novice! The site should be updated today if anyone cares to view and critique. I will post the address later on today.